# got error while compiling memory allocation code of c++ program

Tags: c++

i'm writing a memory allocation program in c++ but got an error in the program.
i can't understand what is happening.
Please help.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{
    int *m_ptr;
    private:
        void Test(){
            m_ptr = new int(4);
        }
        ~Test(class Test){
            cout<<"Object gets destroyed..";
        }
};

int main(){
    Test *ptr = new Test();
    delete [] ptr;
}
```

**also i'm new to c++**

Comment: `got an error` Please quote the complete error messages, which should point out the problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private:
    void Test(){
        m_ptr = new int(4);
    }
```

should be

```
public:
    Test(){
        m_ptr = new int(4);
    }
```

There's no return type on a constructor, and if you want to use it in `main` it should be public.

And

```
    ~Test(class Test){
        cout<<"Object gets destroyed..";
    }
```

should be

```
    ~Test(){
        cout<<"Object gets destroyed..";
    }
```

There are no parameters for a destructor and they should (almost always) be public.

Also

```
delete [] ptr;
```

should be

```
delete ptr;
```

If you allocate with `new` then you deallocate with `delete`. Only if you allocate with `new[]` do you deallocate with `delete[]`.

There's a lot of basic syntax errors in a very small program. Whatever source you are looking at to learn the structure of a C++ program cannot be very good. It might be worth spending some time practicing simpler topics before doing memory allocation (which is a very complex subject),

Thanks to dvix and user for helping me spot additional problems in the code.

Comment: D-tor is also buggy (should `delete [] m_ptr`). The `Test` class requires specialized copy c-tor and move c-tor, otherwise they will easily run to double free and memory leaks.

Comment: thanks bro. now i get understand where i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructors and destructors (that are called) should be `public` not `private`.

Also, destructors don't take any arguments. It should be

```
~Test() {
    cout<<"Object gets destroyed..";
}
```